# import excel file to oracle database using java without use of poi

Tags: java, oracle11g

i have imported data from oracle database to excel(.xls) file
but while doing in reverse the metadata i.e. the size of datatype cannot be recovered.
Please help.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10248953/6743203

Comment: Can you give more information on the steps you are following, and what errors you are seeing?